# Unable to play audio files in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I need help figuring out what is wrong in this code. I've searched how to implement the ListView OnItemClickListeners, but I can't do it. When I click on listitem the app crash and media player does not work.

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
file = new File( directory + "/Record" );
File list[] = file.listFiles();

for( int i=0; i<5; i++)
{


         myList.add( list[i].getName() );

}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter); //Set all the file in the list.


listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        final String res = new String(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Record/");

        playSong(res+myList.get(position));
    }
    private void playSong(String songPath) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check my audio player tutorial project here: 
https://github.com/GIGAMOLE/NEON